# How to add support for access modifiers?

Tags: python-3.x, yacc, lex

I'm writing compiler for myself and getting an error when I'm trying to add support for the `public`, `private`, `protected`. Parser works well when there is no access specifiers in example below
Lexer:

```py
import argparse
import ply.lex as lex

tokens = (
    'NUMBER',
    'PLUS',
    'MINUS',
    'TIMES',
    'DIVIDE',
    'MOD',
    'EQUALS',
    'COLON',
    'LPAREN',
    'RPAREN',
    'LBRACE',
    'RBRACE',
    'SEMICOLON',
    'COMMA',
    'IDENTIFIER',
    'TYPE',
    'STRUCT',
    'NAMESPACE',
    'INTERFACE',
    'ACCESS_SPECIFIER',
    'TEMPLATE',
    'LESS_THAN',
    'GREATER_THAN',
    'IF',
    'ELSE',
    'EQ',
    'NEQ',
    'LTE',
    'GTE',
    'NAMESPACE_OPERATOR',
    'FOR',
    'WHILE',
    'FOREACH',
    'LBRACKET',
    'RBRACKET',
    'TYPEDEF',
    'INCLUDE',
    'THIS',
    'INCREMENT',
    'DECREMENT',
    'PREFIX_INCREMENT',
    'PREFIX_DECREMENT',
    'RETURN',
    'OBJECT_INITIALIZATION',
    'OBJECT_DECLARATION',
    'BIT_SHIFT_LEFT',
    'BIT_SHIFT_RIGHT',
    'XOR',
    'AND',
    'OR',
    'MEMBER_FUNCTION_ACCESS',
    'MEMBER_ACCESS',
    'TRUE',
    'FALSE',
    'LOGICAL_AND',
    'LOGICAL_OR',
    'IMPLEMENTS',
    'CONSTRUCTOR',
    'DESTRUCTOR',
    'FUNCTION_DECLARATION',
    'DOT'
)

t_PLUS               = r'\+'
t_MINUS              = r'-'
t_TIMES              = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE             = r'/'
t_MOD                = r'%'
t_EQUALS             = r'='
t_COLON              = r':'
t_LPAREN             = r'\('
t_RPAREN             = r'\)'
t_LBRACE             = r'\{'
t_RBRACE             = r'\}'
t_SEMICOLON          = r';'
t_COMMA              = r','
t_IDENTIFIER         = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
t_LESS_THAN          = r'<'
t_GREATER_THAN       = r'>'
t_EQ                 = r'=='
t_NEQ                = r'!='
t_LTE                = r'<='
t_GTE                = r'>='
t_NAMESPACE_OPERATOR = r'::'
t_LBRACKET           = r'\['
t_RBRACKET           = r'\]'
t_LOGICAL_AND        = r'&&'
t_LOGICAL_OR         = r'\|\|'
t_DOT                = r'\.'

def t_TYPE(t):
    r'\b(int|void|char|long|uint128|uint256|uint64|uint32)\b'
    return t

def t_STRUCT(t):
    r'\bstruct\b'
    return t

def t_NAMESPACE(t):
    r'\bnamespace\b'
    return t

def t_INTERFACE(t):
    r'\binterface\b'
    return t

def t_TEMPLATE(t):
    r'\btemplate\b'
    return t

def t_IF(t):
    r'\bif\b'
    return t

def t_ELSE(t):
    r'\belse\b'
    return t

def t_FOR(t):
    r'\bfor\b'
    return t

def t_WHILE(t):
    r'\bwhile\b'
    return t

def t_FOREACH(t):
    r'\bforeach\b'
    return t

def t_TYPEDEF(t):
    r'\btypedef\b'
    return t

def t_INCLUDE(t):
    r'\#include \<[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\>'
    return t

def t_THIS(t):
    r'\bthis->\b'
    return t

def t_INCREMENT(t):
    r'\+\+'
    return t

def t_DECREMENT(t):
    r'--'
    return t

def t_PREFIX_INCREMENT(t):
    r'\+\+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    return t

def t_PREFIX_DECREMENT(t):
    r'--[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    return t

def t_RETURN(t):
    r'\breturn\b'
    return t

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

def t_COMMENT(t):
    r'//.*'
    pass

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

t_ignore  = ' \t'

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

def t_TRUE(t):
    r'true'
    t.value = True
    return t

def t_FALSE(t):
    r'false'
    t.value = False
    return t

def t_OBJECT_INITIALIZATION(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\s*(::\s*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)?\s+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\s*=\s*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\s*(::\s*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)?\s*\([^\)]*\)\s*;'
    return t

def t_OBJECT_DECLARATION(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\s*(::\s*[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)?\s+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\s*;'
    return t

def t_BIT_SHIFT_LEFT(t):
    r'<<'
    return t

def t_BIT_SHIFT_RIGHT(t):
    r'>>'
    return t

def t_XOR(t):
    r'\^'
    return t

def t_AND(t):
    r'&'
    return t

def t_OR(t):
    r'\|'
    return t

def t_MEMBER_FUNCTION_ACCESS(t):
    r'\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\([^\)]*\)'
    return t

def t_MEMBER_ACCESS(t):
    r'\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    return t

def t_IMPLEMENTS(t):
    r'\bimplements\b'
    return t

def t_CONSTRUCTOR(t):
    r'\bconstructor\b'
    return t

def t_DESTRUCTOR(t):
    r'\bdestructor\b'
    return t

def t_ACCESS_SPECIFIER(t):
    r'\b(public|protected|private)\b'

def t_DOR(t):
    r'\.'
    return t

lexer = lex.lex()
```

Here is the parser:

```py
from ply import yacc
from lexer import tokens

precedence = (
    ('left', 'PLUS', 'MINUS'),
    ('left', 'TIMES', 'DIVIDE'),
    ('left', 'BIT_SHIFT_RIGHT', 'BIT_SHIFT_LEFT', 'AND', 'OR', 'XOR'),
)

def p_program(p):
    '''program : statement
               | program statement'''
    if len(p) == 2:
        p[0] = [p[1]]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] + [p[2]]

def p_statement_typedef(p):
    'statement : TYPEDEF TYPE IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('typedef', p[2], p[3])

def p_statement_namespace(p):
    'statement : NAMESPACE IDENTIFIER LBRACE statements RBRACE'
    p[0] = ('namespace', p[2], p[4])

def p_statements(p):
    '''statements : statement
                  | statements statement
                  | empty'''
    if len(p) == 2:
        if p[1] == ('empty',):
            p[0] = []
        else:
            p[0] = [p[1]]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] + [p[2]]

def p_template(p):
    'template : TEMPLATE LESS_THAN IDENTIFIER GREATER_THAN'
    p[0] = ('template', p[3])

def p_statement_template_struct(p):
    'statement : template STRUCT IDENTIFIER LBRACE members RBRACE SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('template_struct', p[1], ('struct', p[3], p[5]))


def p_statement_struct(p):
    'statement : STRUCT IDENTIFIER LBRACE members RBRACE SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('struct', p[2], p[4])        

def p_members(p):
    '''members : member
               | members member
               | method_declaration
               | members method_declaration
               | access_specifier_block
               | members access_specifier_block'''
    if len(p) == 2:
        p[0] = [p[1]]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] + [p[2]]

def p_method_declaration(p):
    'method_declaration : TYPE IDENTIFIER LPAREN parameters RPAREN SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('method_declaration', p[1], p[2], p[4])

def p_member(p):
    'member : TYPE IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('member', p[1], p[2])

def p_statement_function_no_params(p):
    'statement : TYPE IDENTIFIER LPAREN RPAREN LBRACE statements RBRACE'
    p[0] = ('function', p[1], p[2], [], p[6])

def p_statement_function(p):
    'statement : TYPE IDENTIFIER LPAREN parameters RPAREN LBRACE statements RBRACE'
    p[0] = ('function', p[1], p[2], p[4], p[7])

def p_parameters(p):
    '''parameters : TYPE IDENTIFIER
                  | parameters COMMA TYPE IDENTIFIER'''
    if len(p) == 3:
        p[0] = [(p[1], p[2])]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] + [(p[3], p[4])]

def p_access_specifier_block(p):
    '''access_specifier_block : ACCESS_SPECIFIER COLON members'''
    p[0] = (p[1], p[3])

def p_statement_assign(p):
    'statement : IDENTIFIER EQUALS expression SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('assign', p[1], p[3])

def p_expression_binop(p):
    '''expression : expression PLUS expression
                  | expression MINUS expression
                  | expression TIMES expression
                  | expression DIVIDE expression
                  | expression EQ expression
                  | expression NEQ expression
                  | expression LESS_THAN expression
                  | expression GREATER_THAN expression
                  | expression LTE expression
                  | expression GTE expression
                  | expression BIT_SHIFT_RIGHT expression
                  | expression BIT_SHIFT_LEFT expression
                  | expression AND expression
                  | expression OR expression
                  | expression XOR expression'''
    p[0] = (p[2], p[1], p[3])

def p_expression_identifier(p):
    'expression : IDENTIFIER'
    p[0] = ('id', p[1])    

def p_statement_return(p):
    'statement : RETURN expression SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('return', p[2])

def p_statement_if(p):
    'statement : IF LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE statements RBRACE'
    p[0] = ('if', p[3], p[6])

def p_statement_if_else(p):
    'statement : IF LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE statements RBRACE ELSE LBRACE statements RBRACE'
    p[0] = ('if-else', p[3], p[6], p[10])

def p_statement_increment(p):
    'statement : IDENTIFIER INCREMENT SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('increment', p[1])

def p_statement_decrement(p):
    'statement : IDENTIFIER DECREMENT SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('decrement', p[1])

def p_statement_prefix_increment(p):
    'statement : INCREMENT IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('prefix_increment', p[2])

def p_statement_prefix_decrement(p):
    'statement : DECREMENT IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('prefix_decrement', p[2])

def p_declaration(p):
    'declaration : TYPE IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('declare', p[1], p[2])

def p_declaration_init(p):
    'declaration : TYPE IDENTIFIER EQUALS expression SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('declare_init', p[1], p[2], p[4])

def p_statement_declaration(p):
    'statement : declaration'
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_expression_bool(p):
    '''expression : TRUE
                  | FALSE'''
    p[0] = ('bool', p[1])

def p_statement_while(p):
    'statement : WHILE LPAREN expression RPAREN LBRACE statements RBRACE'
    p[0] = ('while', p[3], p[6])

def p_expression_number(p):
    'expression : NUMBER'
    p[0] = ('number', p[1])

def p_statement_interface(p):
    'statement : INTERFACE IDENTIFIER LBRACE members RBRACE SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('interface', p[2], p[4])

def p_constructor(p):
    'constructor : CONSTRUCTOR LPAREN parameters RPAREN LBRACE statements RBRACE'
    p[0] = ('constructor', p[3], p[6])

def p_destructor(p):
    'destructor : DESTRUCTOR LPAREN RPAREN LBRACE statements RBRACE'
    p[0] = ('destructor', p[6])

def p_struct_body(p):
    '''struct_body : access_specifier_block
                   | struct_body access_specifier_block
                   | statement
                   | struct_body statement
                   | constructor
                   | struct_body constructor
                   | destructor
                   | struct_body destructor'''
    if len(p) == 2:
        p[0] = [p[1]]
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] + [p[2]]

def p_statement_method_implementation(p):
    'statement : IDENTIFIER COLON COLON IDENTIFIER LPAREN parameters RPAREN LBRACE statements RBRACE'
    p[0] = ('method_impl', p[1], p[4], p[6], p[9])

def p_statement_function_call(p):
    'statement : IDENTIFIER DOT IDENTIFIER LPAREN parameters RPAREN SEMICOLON'
    p[0] = ('function_call', p[1], p[3], p[5])
def p_empty(p):
    'empty :'
    pass

def p_error(p):
    if p:
        print(f"Syntax error at '{p.value}' at line {p.lineno}, position {p.lexpos}")
    else:
        print("Syntax error at EOF")

parser = yacc.yacc()
```

Here is the example I'm trying to parse:

```cpp
typedef int myInt;

namespace Test {    
    template<class T>
    struct Point {
        int x; 
        int y;
        int myMethod(int a, int b); 
    private:
        uint64 z;
    };
}
```

main.py:

```py
import argparse
from parser import parser

def main():
    parser_arg = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parse a program.')
    parser_arg.add_argument('filename', help='the name of the file to parse')

    args = parser_arg.parse_args()

    with open(args.filename, 'r') as file:
        source_code = file.read()

    result = parser.parse(source_code)

    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is an error:

```
Syntax error at ':' at line 9, position 125
Syntax error at '}' at line 11, position 140
None
```